# Enqueue to a Scala Queue another Scala Queue

Tags: scala, queue

I want to enqueue to a Scala Queue another Scala Queue. Something like:

```
val q1 = Queue(1,2,3,4)
val q2 = Queue(5,6,7,8)
```

I want to get a result like:

```
val q3 = Queue(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

I already try this:

```
val q3 = (0 until q2.length).map(ind => q1.enqueue(q2(ind)))
```

But it return an  IndexedSeq[Unit] like below:

```
Vector((), (), (), ())
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue
val q1 = Queue(1,2,3,4)
val q2 = Queue(5,6,7,8)
val q3 = q1 ++ q2
q3: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int] = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Or in mutable way:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
val q1 = Queue(1,2,3,4)
val q2 = Queue(5,6,7,8)
val q3 = q1 ++= q2
q3: q1.type = Queue(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: Not real required to be mutable :) update to requirements.

Comment: ahh, you're right, different method, though :)) thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Please try read scala api documentation for more details:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.html

And in general queue don't have much use in scala because they easily could be replaced with List.

there is very usefull method at the top. Will solve this problem.

Comment: ++[B](that: GenTraversableOnce[B]): Queue[B]
[use case]
Returns a new immutable queue containing the elements from the left hand operand followed by the elements from the right hand operand. The element type of the immutable queue is the most specific superclass encompassing the element types of the two operands.

This is from documentation page. Top method.

Comment: don t worry I just need to wait 7 minute to be allowed for validation